# Date Range Picker - show calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

I'm trying to implement a button that makes appear a calendar. It's from [here](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#license). When I do it in a empty file and I load it, it works but when I try to mix with my code nothing appears.
The button is inside a drop down menu with two more buttons: "Categoria" and "Nome", that when clicked a search/filter box appears for each one.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

                <div class="dropDown">
                <button onclick="dropDown()" class="dropBtn">Filtro</button>
                <div id="myDropDown" class="dropDown-content">
                      <button onclick="containCatText()" class="catbtn">Categoria</button>
                        <div id="myDropdownCat" class="catdown-content">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Procurar.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
                        </div>
                      <button onclick="calendar()" class="calbtn">Date</button>
                        <div id="myCal" class="cal-content">
                          <input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />
                        </div>
                        <script>
                          $(function containText() {
                            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                              opens: 'left'
                            }, function(start, end, label) {
                              console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                            });
                          });

                          function calendar() {
                            $('input[name="daterange"]').focus();
                          }

                        </script>
                      <button onclick="containNamText()" class="nambtn">Nome</button>
                        <div id="myDropdownNam" class="namdown-content">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Procurar.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <script>
            function containCatText() {
                document.getElementById("myDropdownCat").classList.toggle("show");
            }
            function containNamText() {
                document.getElementById("myDropdownNam").classList.toggle("show");
            }
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (!event.target.matches('.catbtn')) {
                    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("catdown-content");
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (!event.target.matches('.nambtn')) {
                    var dropdowns1 = document.getElementsByClassName("namdown-content");
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            </script>
            <script>
            function dropDown() {
                document.getElementById("myDropDown").classList.toggle("Show");
            }
            </script>
```

Am I missing something?
I'm having this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function
>       at HTMLInputElement. (Feeds:226)
>       at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3) (anonymous) @ Feeds:226 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3 q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're placing the initialization code inside the click event, so you'll need to move that outside of the function. Since there doesn't seem to be any other way, you'll need to mimic the input press by focusing it

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<button onclick="calendar()" class="calbtn">Date</button>
<div id="myCal" class="cal-content">
  <input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />
</div>
<script>
  $(function containText() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
      opens: 'left'
    }, function(start, end, label) {
      console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    });
  });

  function calendar() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').focus();
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. When I run code snippet it seems to work but in my case still nothing happens... What could be my problem?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing how you're implementing it. If you could give me some more info I could try to help

Comment: Okay thank you! The Data button is in a drop down menu with a Categoria and Nome buttons that open a search/filter that works. I will update the question above with that implementation

Comment: I see the jquery is missing from the code now but I guess you still have it in since you got that error. I'm guessing your placing jquery in after daterangepicker wich would cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jQuery `trigger` event, like so:

```
$('.calbtn').on('click', function() {
   $('input[name="daterange"]').trigger('click');
});
```

See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) for more info.

Comment: Not sure if I understand... Supposedly should I put my jquery inside your function, "$('.calbtn').on('click', function() {"?

Comment: Don't use the HTML `onclick` at all. Best practice is to put all your js inside a js file (or in your case, a script tag), not the HTML. That being said, put this code inside your script tag (preferably, after you initiate the calendar). Or you can wrap this code inside a function and call it from HTML with the `onclick`.